# SRC folder of Google App Engine Flexible project is empty

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I was fallowing a [guide](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/create-flexible?hl=uk) of creating a new java project in IntellIJ IDEA and in the end I got empty folder src without any files or sub-folders in it. Does anybody know what did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Any errors in [the log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? Try importing `build.gradle` from scratch. Ensure the project is valid and command line `gradle build` doesn't return any errors.

Comment: @CrazyCoder no, I have not any errors in log file, only info records

Comment: See if command line gradle build reports any errors.

Comment: @CrazyCode I used gradle: http://tinypic.com/r/f1mixl/9

Comment: @user3057645 That's kind of expected for a *new* project - it'll be empty until you start adding stuff to it. If you were expecting something else you should mentioned what and why.

Comment: @DanCornilescu so you want to say that all files in 'src' on next image were added manually? https://cloud.google.com/tools/images/intellij-vcs-checkout.png?hl=uk

Comment: Possibly, note that that image is in the section for an **existing** project, not a new one... My point is that you need to describe your problem better: you're asking what you did wrong but you don't mention what you actually did (the pointer to the guide is OK, but it only tells us what you were supposed to do).

Comment: @user3057634 also note that (aside from my answer below), that if you use the wizard and select to generate an `app.yaml`, the src folder will contain a template `app.yaml` under `src/main/appengine` for you to start from.

Answer (score 1):

I work on this plugin. This is unfortunately all that is available for now using the App Engine flexible new project wizard. I would suggest instead to start from publicly available AE flex github project (such as the one referenced in [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/quickstart)). You could also start with any Java 8 project as well since you are running on flex - you can then use the plugin to add App Engine flexible support to it:

```
Tools > Google Cloud Tools > Add App Engine support > Google App Engine Flexible
```

This will generate a template `app.yaml` for you and also expose the App Engine plugin features (like deploying to GCP).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the project that you created. Since you were creating a new project, your project has an empty `src` folder with a `.iml` file. As *eshaul* commented, if you selected `Create app.yaml` box in the wizard, then the project will contain a template `app.yaml` under `src/main/appengine`.

Regarding [this image](https://cloud.google.com/tools/images/intellij-vcs-checkout.png), the files in the project `helloworld` are imported from `Cloud Repositories`. The procedure to import an existing project in Cloud Source Repositories is explained in the same tutorial that you was following (Checking out an existing project).